# How can I get values between the last two forward slashes (/) in URL column? in SQL

Tags: sql, parsing, substring, reverse

Hello and thank you in advance for your help!

I have a column named "URL" and need to parse out the DocID, in the returned value below it is "87".

```
http://SiteName-Domain/Announcements/Attachments/**87**/Document.DOCX
```

How can query the values between the last two forward slashes (/) to get the DocId?

I can get the values after the last slash but not sure how to between the last two:

```
Select RIGHT(ax.URL, (CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(ax.URL),0))-1),* from     SPListItemAttachments ax
```

Here is another attempt getting closer but I'm doing something wrong

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(URL, CHARINDEX('/', URL)
, CHARINDEX('/',URL) - CHARINDEX('/', URL) + Len('/')) from SPListItemAttachments
```

Comment: Are you missing some tags?

Comment: please tag your dbms and show us your attempt.

Comment: It also might be trivial to do this in your scripting language, if we new what it was.

Comment: All set. Added my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic not using Len and substr with explanations below in SQL Server

```
declare @mytext varchar(max) = 'http://SiteName-Domain/Announcements/Attachments/**87**/Document.DOCX'
```

-- explanation --

```
select charindex('/',reverse(@mytext)) -- get 1st position of /
select right(@mytext,charindex('/',reverse(@mytext))) -- get the text from right
select replace(@mytext,right(@mytext,charindex('/',reverse(@mytext))),'') -- replace the first right text to get extract what you are after of/
```

-- effectively your script --

```
select  right(replace(@mytext,right(@mytext,charindex('/',reverse(@mytext))),''),  charindex('/',reverse(replace(@mytext,right(@mytext,charindex('/',reverse(@mytext))),'')))-1)  -- then extract from the right text after /
```